# Why is RAM usage different when viewing running services and cached processes

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ram

After experiencing several out-of-memory restarts, I decided to check which applications were consuming my phone's resources.

Going to **Settings** > **Developer Options** > **Running Services**, I found that by switching between **Running Services** and **Cached Processes**, the RAM usage is totally different as can be seen in the pictures below

[image: RAM used by running services]
*RAM used by running services*

[image: RAM used by cached processes]
*RAM used by cached processes*

What is the cause of this disparity in the values and which of them should I use to check for memory-hogging apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the dark bar, light bar and white bar stand for *totally* different things.

[image: A] [image: B]

In Picture 1, the dark bar means "RAM used by the operating system", the light bar means "RAM used by user apps" and the white bar means **"RAM available for use"** (not actually "free").

In Picture 2, the dark bar means "RAM occupied by processed", the light bar means "RAM used for caching apps (for faster startup)" (can be freed for use) and the white bar means **"totally unused RAM / free RAM"**.

That's why the size of "Free" in picture 1 roughly equals the size of both "Cached" and "Free" in picture 2.

Comment: Beat me to it :) You may wish to add that, confirming your analysis, "system + apps" from the first screenshot rawly matches "used" in the second, plus "free" from the first minus "cached" from the second calculates to "free" in the latter – which means "free" in the first screenshots includes "cached" from the second.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm rather surprised I didn't notice it earlier. Thank you for pointing it out. Unfortunately though my lack of observation has already earned me a down vote. :-(

Comment: @Izzy Last paragraph :) No edits.

Comment: Oops. But what about "System" + "Apps" summing up to "Used"? #D